# Layer4 "Connection refused" with haproxy

Tags: haproxy

I need some advise on how to setup **haproxy**. I have two web-servers up and running. For testing they run a simple node server on port 8080.

Now on my haproxy server I start haproxy which gives me the following:

```
$> /usr/sbin/haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg 
[WARNING] 325/202628 (16) : Server node-backend/server-a is DOWN, reason: Layer4 connection problem, info: "Connection refused", check duration: 0ms. 1 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
[WARNING] 325/202631 (16) : Server node-backend/server-b is DOWN, reason: Layer4 timeout, check duration: 2001ms. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
[ALERT] 325/202631 (16) : backend 'node-backend' has no server available!
```

Just one note: If I do:

```
haproxy$> wget server-a:8080
```

I get the response from the node server.

Here is my haproxy.cfg:

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------  
# Global settings
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
global
    log         127.0.0.1 local2

    chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
    maxconn     4000
    user        haproxy
    group       haproxy

    stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# common defaults that all the 'listen' and 'backend' sections will
# use if not designated in their block
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
defaults
    mode                    tcp
    log                     global
    option                  tcplog
    option                  dontlognull
    option http-server-close
#   option forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8
    option                  redispatch
    retries                 3
    timeout http-request    10s
    timeout queue           1m
    timeout connect         10s
    timeout client          1m
    timeout server          1m
    timeout http-keep-alive 10s
    timeout check           10s
    maxconn                 3000

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# main frontend which proxys to the backends
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
frontend  www
    bind                        *:80
    default_backend             node-backend

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# round robin balancing between the various backends
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
backend node-backend
   balance roundrobin
   mode tcp
   server server-a 172.19.0.2:8080 check
   server server-b 172.19.0.3:8080 check
```

If I remove the `check` option it seems to work. Any suggestions how I can fix this checking mechanism of haproxy?

Answer (score 6):

You need to get exact ip address of your server with the help of command

```
ifconfig
```

and correct the below address in your `haproxy.cfg` file:

```
172.19.0.2:8080
172.19.0.3:8080
```

or modify line like below

```
server server-a server-a:8080 check
server server-b server-b:8080 check
```

Comment: If using Docker remember that you must set the networking to `--network host` if you wish to use `127.0.0.1`. That's if it's on the same computer.

Comment: @basickarl could be helpful if you can give an example

Answer (score 2):

Remove `mode tcp` and change it to `mode http`.

I'm just guessing here but I suppose haproxy is doing a tcp check against your web server and the web server can not respond to it.

In `mode http` it checks the web server in http mode and expects a "response 200" for L4 check
and expects a string (whatever you defined) as a L7 check.

**L4**:

```
backend node-backend
   balance roundrobin
   mode http #(NOT NEEDED IF DEFINED IN DEFAULTS)
   option httpchk
   server server-a 172.19.0.2:8080 check
   server server-b 172.19.0.3:8080 check
```

**L7**:

```
backend node-backend
   balance roundrobin
   mode http #(NOT NEEDED IF DEFINED IN DEFAULTS)
   option httpchk get /SOME_URI
   http-check expect status 200
   server server-a 172.19.0.2:8080 check
   server server-b 172.19.0.3:8080 check
```

Comment: I though that L4 is set using `mode tcp` What exactly. So what exactly defines L4 or L7?

Comment: L4 is a Layer 4 Check (OSI Model) L7 is a Layer 7 Check.
so L4 would reply with status codes 500,404,200,301...etc.
L7 would look at the "Content" returned by the request...http headers,json strings, whatever in the body of the result

Answer (score 2):

Another note related to @basickarl's comment on docker. If you are sending into a docker (docker-compose) instance (namely where you have multiple instances of service running) you likely need to define the docker resolver and use it for dns resolution on your backend:

resolver:

```
resolvers docker_resolver
nameserver dns 127.0.0.11:53
```

backend usage of resolver:

```
backend main
    balance roundrobin
    option http-keep-alive
    server haproxyapp app:80 check inter 10s resolvers docker_resolver resolve-prefer ipv4
```

Comment: Can you please explain the `backend main` section, especially the last line.

Answer (score 1):

i tryied all this answers nothing works for me. only put the gateway IP of network work, for default bridge is 172.17.0.1.

In the servers put the : and with this haproxy connects with success.

My example of custom network with fixed ips and gateway:

```
----- haproxy config

backend be_pe_8545
    mode http
    balance     roundrobin

    server p1 172.20.0.254:18545 check inter 10s
    server p2 172.20.0.254:28545 check inter 10s

----- docker app / network
  docker_app: ... 
    networks:
      public_network:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.50 

  public_network:
    name: public_network
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet:  172.20.0.0/24
          gateway: 172.20.0.254
```